# Charts Template on other PC

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I made some charts as templates, and they have to always be the same, but also be able to function when some other users want to use it (to open).

How to fix this macro so anyone can use the same templates but without manually changing path/location of charts? Is there a way that the macro "detects" the folder where the charts are?

Until now I have to change path every time someone else wants to use templates. Its a waste of time and also a security issue.

```
Sub Schaltfläche3_Klicken()

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim FileChosen As Integer
Dim FileName As String
Dim tempWB As Workbook
Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

' *** Define the location ***
fd.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\MirzaV\Desktop\Original"
fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

FileChosen = fd.Show
If FileChosen = -1 Then
For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
    Set tempWB = Workbooks.Open(fd.SelectedItems(i))
    Call ReadDataFromSourceFile(tempWB)
Next i
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

Private Sub ReadDataFromSourceFile(src As Workbook)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


' *** Creating Charts ***

Range("A:A,J:K").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Tabelle1!$A:$A,Tabelle1!$J:$K")
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
    "C:\Users\MirzaV\Desktop\Templates\Einlaßheizung.crtx" _
    )
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 1
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 1").Height = 240.9448818898
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 1").Width = 453.5433070866
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
Selection.Caption = "CS - Einlassheizung ()"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Select
Selection.Caption = "Temperatur (°C)"
Columns("A:C").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Tabelle1!$A:$C")
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
    "C:\Users\MirzaV\Desktop\Templates\Einlaßdruck.crtx" _
    )
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 2").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 1
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 2").Height = 240.9448818898
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 2").Width = 453.5433070866
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
Selection.Caption = "CS - Einlassdruck ()"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Select
Selection.Caption = "Druck (mbar)"
Range("A:A,D:F").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Tabelle1!$A:$A,Tabelle1!$D:$F")
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
    "C:\Users\MirzaV\Desktop\Templates\ModulTemperatur.crtx")
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 3").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 1
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 3").Height = 240.9448818898
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 3").Width = 453.5433070866
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
Selection.Caption = "CS - C1 - CC ()"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Select
Selection.Caption = "Temperatur (°C)"
Range("A:A,G:I").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Tabelle1!$A:$A,Tabelle1!$G:$I")
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
    "C:\Users\MirzaV\Desktop\Templates\ModulTemperatur.crtx")
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 4").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 1
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 4").Height = 240.9448818898
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 4").Width = 453.5433070866
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
Selection.Caption = "CS - C2 - CC ()"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Select
Selection.Caption = "Temperatur (°C)"
Sheets("Tabelle2").Select
Columns("A:E").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Tabelle2!$A:$E")
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
    "C:\Users\MirzaV\Desktop\Templates\Auslasskonzentration.crtx")
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 1
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 1").Height = 240.9448818898
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 1").Width = 453.5433070866
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
Selection.Caption = "CS - Auslasskonzentration ()"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Select
Selection.Caption = "Auslasskonz. (ppb)"
Sheets("Tabelle1").Select
Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 4").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 4").IncrementLeft 480
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 4").IncrementTop 223
Range("U15").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 3").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 3").IncrementLeft 480
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 3").IncrementTop -22
Range("O8").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 2").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 2").IncrementLeft 27
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 2").IncrementTop 223
Range("L11").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 1").IncrementLeft 27
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 1").IncrementTop -22
Range("L9").Select
Sheets("Tabelle2").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Activate
ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
Sheets("Tabelle1").Select
Range("C27").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 5").Activate


' *** Auswertungs Tabelle (Temperatur, Druck, min und max ***

Range("M1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "T01min"
Range("N1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "T01max"
Range("O1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "dT01"
Range("P1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "T01mw"
Range("Q1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "T02min"
Range("R1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "T02max"
Range("S1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "dT02"
Range("T1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "T02mw"
Range("U1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "P0min"
Range("V1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "P0max"
Range("W1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "p0mw"
Range("X1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "p1min"
Range("Y1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "p2max"
Range("Z1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "p2mw"
Range("Z2").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 85
Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(C[-3])"
Range("N2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(C[-4])"
Range("O2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"
Range("P2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(C[-6])"
Range("Q2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(C[-6])"
Range("R2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(C[-7])"
Range("S2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"
Range("T2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(C[-9])"
Range("U2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(C[-19])"
Range("V2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(C[-20])"
Range("W2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(C[-21])"
Range("X2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(C[-21])"
Range("Y2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(C[-22])"
Range("Z2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(C[-23])"
Range("M2:Z2").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
Range("M1:Z2").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Range("M1:Z1").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.Font.Bold = True

    ' *** Close and SaveAs ***
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have several option to solve the issue

1. You can use this path instead

   ```
   %userprofile%/Desktop/Original
   ```

   As an example: For the part

   ```
   ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
   "C:\Users\MirzaV\Desktop\Templates\Einlaßheizung.crtx" _
   )
   ```

   You can replace it with

   ```
   ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
   "%userprofile%\Desktop\Templates\Einlaßheizung.crtx" _
   )
   ```

   Replace all paths like that ans after that ask the users to paste the template folder on their desktops.
2. 2nd option is that if you are on a network; save the templates on a
   shared folder and give the path to that shared folder, as it will
   remain same on the network, you will not have any problem
3. You can use relative path, for example, if the template is in the same folder as of the files, you can use ./  .This  ./ refers to the directory of the file.
4. You can even get the current directory of the file using

   ```
   Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
   ```

   or

   ```
   Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
   ```

   and use the path to make any relative path to the template
5. You can even make the path dynamic by asking the user from where to get the templates, you can use a code like below

   ```
   Sub SelectFolder()
   Dim folder_path As String

   With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       If .Show = -1 Then
           folder_path = .SelectedItems(1)
       End If
   End With

   If folder_path <> "" Then

       MsgBox folder_path
   Else
       MsgBox "No Folder was selected"
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

   This function will open a file dialog, you have to select the folder and it will return the folder path, that path can then be used in your code.

Comment: You mean instead of this:
fd.InitialFileName = "Q:\Objekt\Kundenerklärung\OSRAM\MACROS"

To replace with Appl.ActivW.Path?

Comment: You have = "C:\Users\MirzaV\Desktop\Original", insted of this you can use just = %userprofile%/Desktop/Original. VBA will look for Original folder on desktop  whatever the user is.

Comment: Aha got it, instead of this Location "Dektop" can be any other file Location or? As Long as it has right Name and defined Location??

Comment: i have edited the answer, you can check the point 1 for the edits

Comment: I got it what you asked, but does it have to be Desktop? I wanted to have in another Folders, i tried it and gives me an error...

Comment: In which folder do you want to place? i have given some other ways as well that you can use, the %userprofile% was for the desktop.

Comment: ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
        "%userprofile%\OSRAM\Templates\Einlaßheizung.crtx" _
        )
If I understood you well, this has to be done manually actually (this defining of path for all cases that I have in my Macro?) It is actually the same as I did before, needed to specify Location and paths of all 5 Charts that I got and then run the Macro! My question was to avoid "manually" putting the paths and so on...because other users will use it - and they have to go into the code to specify...what I dont wanna!

Comment: This path is to be defined one time only, after that you do not have to change it, the users just need to place the template folder in the correct location on their PC.

Comment: By the way, what do you meant by change? what is to be changed?

Comment: I meant to Change those Locations for all Charts, like 5 times to put the same Thing you wrote up.."%userprofile%\Desktop\Templates\Einlaßheizung.crtx" _

But can you Show me in a case if it is not Desktop as source? But the file Location that I wrote up in previous post...for my Need it wont be Desktop but some certain Folders...

Comment: and that Desktop code that you wrote isnt working actually...tried it to run, but it gives an error (like the Diagram structure is wrong etc etc..)

Comment: Dear Mirza, I can only help you to an extent, it is not practically possible for me to guide you step by step. In my opinion what I have written till now was enough for someone to get started and solve their problem, if it has not solved yours then maybe you would need someone with you or on call / live to guide you.

Comment: i am going to close it here, if you think the post is not helping, let me know and i shall delete it, so that someone else can answer you.

Comment: Hey man, thank you for your effort. Just give me some time to settle this alone, i didnt see you replied up with a code. I will write here till end of the day!!